# Scala invoke in java

Tags: java, scala

I have a problem with my hello world example in jave using scala.
This is my java file:

```
package com.adam.core;
import org.scala.*;

public class App {
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Hello a = new Hello();
        System.out.println(a.greeting());
    }
}
```

And my scala file Hello.scala:

```
package org.scala;

object Hello {
   val greeting: String = "Hello, world!"
}
```

I add only this to my pom:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I am using java 1.8 in Eclipse with all Scala plugins. I add Natural Scala to project.

When i want to run java file i have an error:

Hello cannot be resolved to a type
at com.adam.core.App.main(App.java:8)

i have this 2 files in src/main/scala and src/main/java

Please help me! Google cant help me any more :(

Comment: Doesnt work, Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method greeting() from the type Hello$.

Comment: `Hello$.MODULE$.greeting` ?

Comment: Hello$ cannot be resolved
What can i do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A scala `object` is not something you instantiate with `new`.

Either access the `greeting` statically (`Hello.greeting()`, with no `new Hello` anywhere), or make the scala type a `class` rather than `object`.

Comment: When i use Hello.gretting i have a error:
Hello cannot be resolved